# Possible to replace slow and HTML5 incompliant Adobe's Air WebKit v6531.9 (Webview)?

Tags: mobile, air, webkit, flash-builder, upgrade

I'm developing a mobile app with Flex Builder. Some part is a webview that uses the webkit version available on the host. But the Adobe AIR version of webkit is slow (real slow) and does not support all HTML5 features such as window.localStorage. The loaded webpage works fine and fast in any other browser.

This is not the ideal situation to test the app. I don't want to debug it on my mobile device each time because it takes longer to deploy the app (and some other issues) to device again and again.

My question is:
Can I update/change/replace the version of adobe's AIR webkit to a newer one?
Resources (webkit.dll) are in:

```
C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\sdks\4.6.0\runtimes\air\win\Adobe AIR\Versions\1.0\Resources
```

I have the latest version of AIR and Flash Builder (4.6), so don't tell me to upgrade.

Is there a 'trick' to do this (for example replace the WebKit.dll with an advanced/newer one)?

Comment: Any luck?  We want to do the same thing.

Comment: Hai @collin, late reply I know. But skip developing in Flash Builder these days. It is not too complicated to use ADT to develop for Android and they support also a Webview that can do all the things I want without problems.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://stlab.adobe.com:8080/@md=d&cd=//compliance/air_3_3/&c=M52@//compliance/air_3_3/WebKit/?ac=83) are the latest sources of Adobe WebKit.
But some files is absent.
I'm trying to build it now.
You can download sources with p4web client (mail me dima@kurilo.su for details).
UPD: I uploaded my sources [here](http://www.kurilo.su/webkit/webkit.7z). You shall unpack it to C:\Distrib\webkit and then shall open C:\Distrib\webkit\adobe\compliance\air_3_3\WebKit\WebKit\WebKit.apolloproj\win\WebKit.air.vc2008.sln in Visual Studio 2008
it old version of WebKit from air 3.3. I hope, it is possible - to upgrade it.
I'm ready to help.

Comment: Yes! I did it!  
1) Download  
2) Open air3_3/WebKit/WebKit/WebKit.apolloproj/win/WebKit.sln  
3) Add air3_3/WebKit/JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.apolloproj  
4) Add air3_3/WebKit/WebCore/WebCore.apolloproj  
5) Edit all bat, sh, perl, python and other scripts  
6) Change sources  
7) Build

Comment: Ah, Thanks for the download, i will try it soon. Was it easy to compile? Because you wrote that it is an unsafe version of webkit. Can i use a free compiler to compile it when there are any problems or unwanted symptoms?

Comment: It is an unsafe just because I edited WeKit sources for my needs.  One file absent in sources.  And I turned off bidirectional features.  As I suppose, you can get new JavaScriptCore and WebCore and try to compile to make new WebKit engine.  I can try to send my project, but it very dirty now. :)