# Video Tag on Adobe AIR webkit

Tags: windows, air, webkit, adobe

After several attempts changing webkit.dll in Adobe AIR runtime, I just cannot enable video tags in AIR webkit.
Someone? An idea?

I already tryed

[Possible to replace slow and HTML5 incompliant Adobe's Air WebKit v6531.9 (Webview)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906652/possible-to-replace-slow-and-html5-incompliant-adobes-air-webkit-v6531-9-webvi)

In fact, the Dmitry Kurilo's DLL works, but don't enable video tag.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: No, using Dmitry Kurilo's DLL works, but don't enable video tag.
Trying others webkit.dll from (Safari, other Internets downloads) application just closes after few seconds.
May be webkit.dll inside Adobe AIR need to be customized?